Letterhead images not getting displayed on actual email
I created a HTML email template and added a letterhead to the template in my sandbox. I can see the images in preview and also when sending test mail using 'Send Test and verify merge fields' button. The images in header and footer are displayed as expected. But, when I'm using this templateId in my EmailToApex class and sending email it is not showing any images in the email. It just shows a white space at the top , then my email content and ]]> in the footer section.

What could be the possible reason for it to work in test and preview but not when directly called from APEX? Any possible ways to fix this? I already tried to edit the letterhead properties and changed height and saved. Still it doesn't show the images. Also, the letterhead is set to, 'Available for all profiles'

Do you have checked this?

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8fCNSAZ
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A7lssSAB

